# Continuity with directional derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I face a problem in my exam 
If a function with two variables is there any relation between continuity and directional derivatives, please explain with example it's really helpful thankyou

Answer (score 2):

There is no relation in the following sense: you can have a continuous function but whose partial derivatives do not exist, and conversely you can find a function whose partial derivatives exist but the function is not continuous. Examples for both cases can be found in the following questions:

[Does existence of partial derivatives implies continuity at a point $(x_0,y_0)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87688/does-existence-of-partial-derivatives-implies-continuity-at-a-point-x-0-y-0)

[Does continuity imply partial derivatives exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825030/does-continuity-imply-partial-derivatives-exist)

Comment: @user349115 Please accept answers which help you..